# How to add ID to <a href> on click using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML like this
How add ID to HTML href with javascript

```
<div class="tab">
    <a href="#">exp</a>
</div>
<div class="tab">
    <a href="#">exp</a>
</div>
<div class="tab">
    <a href="#">exp</a>
</div>
<script>
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("tab"); 
    // loops els
    for(var i = 0, x = els.length; i < x; i++) {
        els[i].onclick = function(){
        x = document.querySelector(".tab> a")
            // do something
            x.id = "expid";
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to add the id to each  tag when I click this. Pls help me. Thks so much

Comment: so you need click first and then need to loop

Comment: `x` is always the first `a`, not related to the element you click on.

Comment: You shouldn't create duplicate IDs, they're supposed to be unique. You should use a class instead.

Comment: As @Barmer mentioned, why would you duplicate ID’s? You won’t know which element you’re referencing. You a class, tag, or tag with a class rather than create duplicate IDs.

Comment: you can set it by using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `document.querySelector()` always returns the first `.tab > a` link in the document. You can `this.querySelector()` to return the link in the DIV that you clicked on instead.

I've changed the code to use a class rather than ID, since you shouldn't have duplicate IDs.

Loop through all the DIVs. If it's the DIV that the user clicked on, add the class, otherwise remove it.

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
// loops els
for (var i = 0, x = els.length; i < x; i++) {
  els[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < els.length; j++) {
      x = els[j].querySelector("a");
      if (els[j] == this) {
        x.classList.add("expid");
      } else {
        x.classList.remove("expid");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.expid {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <a href="#">exp</a>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <a href="#">exp</a>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <a href="#">exp</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thks so much. But I want to click on tag <a> will add a class. Other <a> tags are not added.

Comment: I do it, but it doesn't remove classes when clicking <a> another

Comment: There's nothing in the question about removing classes, only adding them.

Comment: Thks so much again, And Sorry for the incomplete question

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="tabs">
  ... your html code.
</div>


const tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs')

tabs.addEventListener('click', event => {
   const aTag = event.target
   if (aTag.tagName !== 'A') return
   aTag.id = `EXPID#${getIndexIn(aTag, tabs)}`
})

function getIndexIn(element, parent): number
```

What's the meaning to be it?

Answer (score -1):

```
const anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
const ids= [1,2,3,4,5];
let index =0 ;
  for(let a of anchors ){
      a.href=ids[index++]
    }
```

you can try this way it's a cool and easiest what I do with pure js

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about adding to an element when you click on it.